# Join two Models to display in webpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building an application using ASP.NET MVC4 with code first data migrations.  I have an estimates model, a clients model, a DbContext,  and a view model I created.  I am wanting to display the company name in a drop down, with the company name tied to an estimate.  I have a ClientId in both models.  I also created a DbSet<> and that didn't work either when querying against it.

I tried to create a viewmodel that I thought I could simply query against and display through my controller.  I'm not having any luck in getting this to work.  After a day plus of looking on here and other places, I'm out of ideas.

How can I query/join the two models, or query the viewmodel to get the company name associated with the clientId?  Thanks for the help.

Models:

```
public class Estimates
    {
        [Key]
        public int EstimateId { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public decimal EstimateAmount { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime EstimateDate { get; set; }
        public string EstimateNotes { get; set; }
    }

public class Clients
    {
        [Key]
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Estimates> Estimates { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Contracts> Contracts { get; set; }
    }

public class ClientEstimateViewModel
    {
        public Clients Clients { get; set; }
        public Estimates Estimates { get; set; }
    }

public class NovaDb : DbContext
    {
        public NovaDb(): base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Clients> Clients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Estimates> Estimates { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contracts> Contracts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Invoices> Invoices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ClientEstimateViewModel> ClientViewModels { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
NovaDb _db = new NovaDb();
        ClientEstimateViewModel ce = new ClientEstimateViewModel();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model =
                (from r in ce.Clients
                 join x in ce.Estimates
                 where 


            //var model =
            //    from r in _db.Clients
            //    orderby r.CompanyName ascending
            //    select r;
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Do *not* couple your EF entities to your ViewModels. You should have separate ViewModel classes, and your EF entities should be mapped onto your ViewModel (using something like AutoMapper).

Answer (score 0):

Because you've created the relationship between client & estimate in your models, you should be able to create a query like this:

```
 var query = from c in _db.clients
    select new ClientEstimateViewModel
    {
         Clients = c,
         Estimates  = c.Estimates
    }
```

Although you'd have to change your model so Estimates was `public List<Estimates> Estimates { get; set; }`

This would give you a collection of ClientEstimateViewModel which you could then pass to your view

Comment: Are you talking about changing Estimates to: public List<Estimates> Estimates { get; set; } in ClientestimateViewModel?  That didn't quite work.